# Canvas resize photoshop script

Tags: photoshop-script

Would it be possible to write a script to resize each image to the closest round number (for example if the original image is 791x1265px then it could be resized to 800x1300px)

Thanks!

Comment: I have PNG/PSD files so I need resize canvas/artboard for that

Comment: That is not a good question, Welcode to SO, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Answering your question: yes, it's possible to write a script like this.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy You inspires me! anyway that answer was funny though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pretty Easy and small script can do it :) Enjoy**

Note : You have two choices for script; before running script either use static base value (default) or if you want to add prompt on each run then uncomment below line of var base and comment the var base line :) Hope that is what you were looking :)

```
    //get Original Ruler Units;
var origRuler = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;    

    //get Active document scales
var origWidth = app.activeDocument.width;
var origHeight = app.activeDocument.height;

    //define base
var base = 100; //change your base like 10;100 etc; use below code to make a prompt on each run;
//var base = prompt("Enter Your Base number",""); //use this code if you want prompt for each run . uncomment by rermoving first two "//"

    //magical Mathematics XD
var roundWidth = Math.ceil(origWidth / base) * base;
var roundHeight = Math.ceil(origHeight / base) * base;

    //resize canvas
app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas (roundWidth, roundHeight);

    //Restores Original Ruler Units;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = origRuler;
```

Edit: Updated script to avoid ruler units conflicts and changed Math.round to Math.ceil as per @Sergey Suggestion!

Comment: Note that if a user has rulers that aren't pixels this won't work: don't forget to manually set rulers to pixels and then restore original ones. And you probably will want to use `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.round` so that canvas wouldn't shrink, cutting the image.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy thanks for pointing out :) let me know you i'm not that kind of pro with js. all i do is using google and some of my tricks and i arrange all this to make scripts and it works though thanks again for notifying me about MAth.round and ruler units :) Answer Updated

Comment: Thanks! It really helps with my problem.